# django Unicode GET Parameter Values

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm trying to get a GET parameter value that looks like this:
http://someurl/handler.json?&q=%E1%F8%E0%F1%F8%E9

The q parameter in this case is Hebrew.
I'm trying to read the value using the following code:

```
request.GET.get("q", None)
```

I'm getting gybrish instead of the correct text. 
Any idea what's wrong here?  Am I missing some setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query string is in ISO-8859-8, but Django's default encoding is UTF-8. You will have to change either [`DEFAULT_CHARSET`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-charset) or [`HttpRequest.encoding`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.encoding) to ISO-8859-8 to get the correct Unicode data.

Comment: Or, if you can, change your application to use the UTF-8 encoding throughout. Webapps that don't support Unicode are so last century.

Comment: True, but ISO-8859-8 doesn't cover whole Unicode, so you can't say you support Unicode is you support only a small subset of it (ISO-8859-8).

Comment: Doing the following works:
request.encoding = 'ISO-8859-8'
x = unicode(request.GET.get("q", None))

But how do I support the full range of unicode characters?
Doing request.encoding = 'utf-8' does not solve the problem...

Comment: To get a full range of Unicode characters you need to change the input to UTF-8 (in this specific case it would be `q=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%99`). If it's from your website then it shouldn't be a problem, but if it's some external application, you need to change that application.

Comment: Thanks. Actually that string is what FireFox generated when I wrote Hebrew on the address bar...

Comment: Curious, parameters typed into the address bar should usually be UTF-8. They are for me in Firefox, whether I type Hebrew or Latin-1 characters (ISO-8859-1 is my default charset). Anyhow, it's relatively unusual to be typing full URLs with their query-parameters...